# Why does this map return a single number?

Tags: perl, arrays, string-concatenation

I am trying to cut down on the number of code lines I am using but am ending up with a fairly simple problem (although it's stumping me since I am just starting to wrap my head around references)

I am trying to concatenate several values in a particular order.. My code looks like this..

```
my $separator = ":";
my @vals = qw(name last-name first-name phone);
my $return_name;
$return_name = map { 
    $return_name = $return_name . $query->param($_) . $separator 
} @vals;
```

What I am getting is "4", instead of concantenating all into one string.

What I am trying to achieve is a shorter version of ...

```
$return_name = $query->param('name') . 
    $separator . $query->param('last-name') . 
    $separator . $query->param('first_name') . 
    $separator . $query->param('phone');
```

(I'm actually trying to string together about 25 `$query->params`. I only gave four for brevity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is confusion over how `map` works.

`map` takes a list of arguments, performs an operation on the elements of the list and creates a new list from the results.  In scalar context it returns the number of members in the new list.

In most cases you don't want to do an assignment in the `map` operation.

```
# no assignment needed to set @foo
my @foo = map $_+2, 1,2,3; 
# @foo = (3,4,5);
```

The one place where assignment makes sense is if you need to use an operation that would normally change the value of `$_`, but you need to preserve the arguments to map unchanged.

That explanation is not terribly clear.  Check out these examples, they should help clarify what I am saying.  The first shows you map can alter the values it processes:

```
my @foo = qw( fee fie foe fum );
my @bar = map { s/e/-/g } @foo;
# @foo = ( 'f--', 'fi-', 'fo-', 'fum' ); 
# @bar = ( 2, 1, 1, '' );
```

To avoid altering @foo you can do:

```
my @foo = qw( fee fie foe fum );
my @bar = map { my $val = $_; $val =~ s/e/-/g } @foo;
# @foo = ( 'fee', 'fie', 'foe', 'fum' ); 
# @bar = ( 'f--', 'fi-', 'fo-', 'fum' );
```

Or you can do:

use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );

```
my @foo = qw( fee fie foe fum );
my @bar = apply { s/e/-/g } @foo;
# @foo = ( 'fee', 'fie', 'foe', 'fum' ); 
# @bar = ( 'f--', 'fi-', 'fo-', 'fum' );
```

At its most basic `map` works like a specialized form of a `for` loop.  The two chunks of code produce the exact same result:

```
my @foo = map {$_ * 2} 1..5;

my @bar;
for (1..5) {
     my $val = $_ * 2;
     push @bar, $val;
}
```

I hope this have given you some help in learning how to think about `map`. Once you have learned to use it (and related constructs like `grep` and `apply`) you will be able to concisely express ideas that can incredibly verbose when built using normal looping code.

Comment: daotoad, that was the best answer I could have gotten for this. I mean everyone has been incredibly helpful but your answer really helped me most to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

`map` returns a list, not a string.  Try this:

```
$return_name = join $separator, map { $query->param($_) } @vals;
```

Or if you really want to cut the number of lines, try this:

```
my $return_name = join ':', 
    map { $query->param($_) } 
    qw(name last-name first-name phone);
```

(The one-line version was inspired by dsm's answer.)

Comment: I am sure dsm's above worked too. jbourque it works like a champ! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
$return_name = map { $return_name = $return_name . $query->param($_) . $separator } @vals;
```

That's a scalar assignment, which gives the map operation scalar context.
[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) in scalar context returns a count of the elements that would have been produced.

While that particular line of code cries out for the use of [join()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html), if you come from a functional programming background, you may be more comfortable with reduce:

```
use List::Util 'reduce';
$return_name = reduce { $a . $query->param($b) . $separator } "", @vals;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
join $separator, 
     map { $query->param($_) } 
     ("name", "last-name", "first-name", "phone");
```

To answer the reason you get '4', it is because you are assigning the resulting arrays' cardinality to a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the good answers you have received, note that

```
$return_name = $return_name . $query->param($_) . $separator;
```

can be written as

```
$return_name .= $query->param($_) . $separator;
```